Calculate the mean of each column and exlude rows
I have data contain 1000 column and 80 rows each five rows correspond to a group (the first column is class column) i want to calculate the mean of each group for all the numerical columns then i want to calculate the absolute value between the mean of each group and it s five rows of this group and eliminate the row that have the highest absolute value and then recalculate the mean of this group using the left four samples, my idea is that i want to eliminate the replicate (the row that is far away from the other four replicates, in R
For example i have this data 

          class    Values1    Values2   
    A1      A        5        10
    A2      A        7        72
    A3      A        4         8 
    A4      A        4        10
    A5      A       30        10
    B1      B       10        20
    B2      B       12        18
    B3      B       70        15
    B4      B       15       100
    B5      B       16        20
    C1      C      120         5
    C2      C       20         2
    C3      C       25        72
    C4      C       21         8
    C5      C       22         3
    MeanA  Na       10        22
    MeanB  Na       24.6      34.6
    MeanC  NA       41.6      18

So as you can see in this example , in Values1, is row A5 that shiuld be exclude for class A, row B3 for class B and row C1 for class C, and in Values2 is   row A2 for values2, row B4 for class B and row C3 for class C and then new results will be :
  class    class   Values1    Values2   
    A1      A        5        10
    A2      A        7        72
    A3      A        4         8 
    A4      A        4        10
    A5      A       30        10
    B1      B       10        20
    B2      B       12        18
    B3      B       70        15
    B4      B       15       100
    B5      B       16        20
    C1      C      120         5
    C2      C       20         2
    C3      C       25        72
    C4      C       21         8
    C5      C       22         3
    MeanA  Na        5         9.5
    MeanB  Na       13.25     18.25
    MeanC  NA       22         4.5

So For class A i exclude A5 to calculate the mean of Values A (mean of A1,A2,A3,A4) and i exclude row A2 to caclutae the mean of Values2 and same logic for the other classes.
I have data contain 80 rows (16 classes) and more than 1000 columns and i want to take the absolute value for to exclude the row that is most diffrent than the mean
Thank you

First I would make a new function:
robustmean <- function(x) mean(x[-which.max(abs(x-mean(x)))])

This takes the mean of the values of a vector x, but first removing the value that is the furthest from the mean of the whole vector.
Then use aggregate with the new function.  This syntax takes away the first column (the row id's) then aggregates all the other columns over class using the supplied function:
aggregate(data=mydata[,-1] , .~class, FUN=robustmean)

which gives you:
  class Values1 Values2
1     A    5.00    9.50
2     B   13.25   18.25
3     C   22.00    4.50

You could rbind this  to the original data if you really wanted to.
You'll need to think about how to deal with missing data if you have any.
I should also point out that R already has an option in the mean function to make a 'trimmed mean' which would exclude the highest and the lowest value.  There are other robust estimators for central tendency to deal with outliers (including the median), you should look into whether your idea for excluding the single most extreme point from each vector is valid and useful.
Intuitively your approach will be unbiased but might have a high variance as it will skew one way or the other depending on which value is excluded, whereas the trimmed mean taking off both the highest and the lowest value might have a lower variance while still being robust.

Thank you for your help, i don't have missing data, i will try the trim option in mean function in R and compare the results, for the trimmed mean , in this example #define data
data = c(22, 25, 29, 11, 14, 18, 13, 13, 17, 11, 8, 8, 7, 12, 15, 6, 8, 7, 9, 12)
mean(data, trim=0.1)
what are the values that are excluded in this example ?

Because there are 20 values R will drop the highest 2 and the lowest 2 with trim=0.1

R Base always super concise!

I got this error message : Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind(M90T680, M91T680, M91T788_1,  :
type (builtin) incorrect pour la variable 'class'

@Reda Does your dataframe have the correct column names? It seems like it cannot find a variable called class and so it is trying to use the function class() instead.

Consider working in a longer format, with more rows instead of columns. Since there are tidyverse tags in the question, here's a tidyverse take. Better readability (IMO).
library(tidyverse)

# -------------------
new_aux <- aux %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Values")) %>% 
  slice_min(by = c(class, name), order_by = abs(value - mean(value)), n = -1) %>%
  summarise(.by = c(class, name), mean_after = mean(value))

Output:
> new_aux
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  class name    mean_after
  <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
1 A     Values1        5  
2 A     Values2        9.5
3 B     Values1       13.2
4 B     Values2       18.2
5 C     Values1       22  
6 C     Values2        4.5

# Or..
> pivot_wider(new_aux, names_from = name, values_from = mean_after)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  class Values1 Values2
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A         5       9.5
2 B        13.2    18.2
3 C        22       4.5

Sample data
aux <- structure(
  list(
    class = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
    Values1 = c(5, 7, 4, 4, 30, 10, 12, 70, 15, 16, 120, 20, 25, 21, 22), 
    Values2 = c(10, 72, 8, 10, 10, 20, 18, 15, 100, 20, 5, 2, 72, 8, 3)), 
  
  row.names = c(NA, -15L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

